# How do I get squashfs and XZ to work?

Tags: linux-mint, snap, squashfs, xz

I'm trying to get snap on Linux Mint, and I've run into too many problems to count.

The first thing I did was install the package (`apt install snap`), and then realised that it is blocked. So I followed the instructions on [the Snapcraft website](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-linux-mint), and deleted `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref`. I then re-installed it (`apt purge snap; apt install snap`), rebooted, and ran `snap install hello-world`. It downloaded the core snap, and when it tried to mount it, it gave me this error message:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (10126) (cannot run unsquashfs: 
-----
Filesystem uses xz compression, this is unsupported by this version
Decompressors available:
    gzip
-----)
```

So I went to the [squashfs LZMA website](https://squashfs-lzma.org/), downloaded the tarball and extracted it.
When I ran `make`, I got these errors:

```
cc -O2  -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -DCOMP_DEFAULT=\"gzip\" -Wall -DGZIP_SUPPORT -DXZ_SUPPORT -DXATTR_SUPPORT -DXATTR_DEFAULT   -c -o mksquashfs.o mksquashfs.c
mksquashfs.c: In function 'create_inode':
mksquashfs.c:987:24: error: called object 'major' is not a function or function pointer
  987 |   unsigned int major = major(buf->st_rdev);
      |                        ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:987:16: note: declared here
  987 |   unsigned int major = major(buf->st_rdev);
      |                ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:988:24: error: called object 'minor' is not a function or function pointer
  988 |   unsigned int minor = minor(buf->st_rdev);
      |                        ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:988:16: note: declared here
  988 |   unsigned int minor = minor(buf->st_rdev);
      |                ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:1011:24: error: called object 'major' is not a function or function pointer
 1011 |   unsigned int major = major(buf->st_rdev);
      |                        ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:1011:16: note: declared here
 1011 |   unsigned int major = major(buf->st_rdev);
      |                ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:1012:24: error: called object 'minor' is not a function or function pointer
 1012 |   unsigned int minor = minor(buf->st_rdev);
      |                        ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c:1012:16: note: declared here
 1012 |   unsigned int minor = minor(buf->st_rdev);
      |                ^~~~~
mksquashfs.c: In function 'dir_scan2':
mksquashfs.c:3527:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'makedev' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 3527 |   buf.st_rdev = makedev(pseudo_ent->dev->major,
      |                 ^~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: mksquashfs.o] Error 1
```

I don't know much about C, but it would be great if I could find a .deb package or something. I tried reinstalling squashfs-tools, then snap, then rebooting, but that didn't do anything.

Could someone please give me some sort of pointer on this?

P.S. If there's a better website for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
sudo apt install liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
git clone https://github.com/plougher/squashfs-tools.git
cd squashfs-tools
git checkout c570c6188811088b12ffdd9665487a2960c997a0
cd squashfs-tools
sed -i 's/#XZ_SUPPORT/XZ_SUPPORT/' Makefile
make -j$(nproc)
make install
```

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately. I'm surprised that the `make -j8` worked on my 2-core processor...

Comment: Either your system is messed up or you don't have glibc-dev paclage installed. It exports the function `major()`. Please confirm you've got `/usr/include/sys/sysmacros.h`

Comment: There's no sys folder in include. Is there meant to be?

Comment: It compiled fine with your example, but snap still couldn't use XZ compression.

Comment: I'm not sure about `snap` and how it interacts with squashfstools. Have you installed them `make install`? Have you removed the already installed package?

Comment: I forgot `make install`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: Great, you may mark it as an answer :-)